# How to add lots (>15) of users on a chrome browser multiple user

Tags: google-chrome, user

Chrome lets you add [multiple users](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en) to the browser. But when you begin to add a lot i.e. more than 15 users you stop being able to access the 'New User' button as well as users  below the fold.

This is because the pop-up window which shows you the list of users does not scroll.

What is the workaround?

Is there another command that lets one access the shortcuts for each user?

Should I try to create multiple instances of chrome and have upto 15 users in each?

Comment: Go play with the developer tools (F12)

Comment: Could you elaborate...

Comment: Press F12. That brings up the Webkit Developer tools, which includes a DOM inspector. You can use this to temporarily change the HTML/styles of a page.

Comment: The list of users is part of the chrome not the page, here is a picture of an earlier chrome version http://img.labnol.org/di/chrome_user_profiles.png New versions have this on the right hnd side.

Comment: I've checked, and it appears to be impossible to alter the style of that bubble, unless you want to compile Chrome yourself. Multiple data dirs (use the `--user-data-dir=path/to/dir` flag) would be the easiest way.